# If not Kona Asphalt Commuter then what?

Tags: commuter, speed, city

Recetly I spotted Kona Asphalt Commuter, one of this series here:
http://www.konaworld.com/asphalt_commuter.cfm?content=dew_plus

Why such bike is so special for me -- because right from the shop I could have all things I want in my dream bike, namely:

- hardtail
- fork w/o suspension
- normal rear derailleur (i.e. just like in MTB bikes)
- disc brakes

And big wheels (this I am not sure about because I didn't ride on 28" wheels, so I don't know if they will be good for me).

I googled, and so far I found another manufacturer making similar bikes -- Trek 7.3 FX Disc:
http://www.trekbikes.com/us/en/bikes/town/fitness/fx/7_3_fx_disc/#/us/en/model/features?url=us/en/bikes/town/fitness/fx/7_3_fx_disc

## Question

Are there other bikes currently manufactured with those **four** features? This is essential because when buying new bike I wouldn't like to modify it right from the start.

*I rephrase: I am looking for a bike which looks and feels MTB, but it is designed for speed while commuting in **the city**. So normal road bikes are no-go, typical city bikes and also bikes with suspensions (even in a seatpost).*

### Little update

More bikes -- Scott with SUB series, and Merida with Speeder (just one model here).

Comment: Of course, if it's only seatpost suspension that is the problem with a given bike, that can be changed out cheaply.

Comment: @Daniel R Hicks, sure, I just made the point. Seatpost is the least problem here.

Comment: What you describe is almost cyclocross/commuter, like the [Kona Honky Inc](http://konaworld.com/road.cfm?content=honky_inc#2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That sort of bike is generally called a hybrid/commuter in the UK (and I think it may be similar in the US).  There are plenty of other manufacturers.  Not all hybrids will meet your requirements but there will be quite a few that do.  You can almost certainly find one with 26" wheels if you prefer too.  I personally find the larger wheels good though, so I would recommend you simply go for a test ride.

The problem with finding them is really a lack of consistency with the terminology 
across shops, countries and manufacturers.  There is also simply the problem that with so many different bike types and configurations bike shops will only stock a selection and your required bike may not be in that selection.  There is however a reasonably good chance if you can find one close in the shop that they will be able to order in the right configuration for you.

Update: tried to reflect confusing terminology a bit better.

Comment: Thank you, but I am not so sure, about that "plenty" :-). As I said before asking, I googled, and there a lot of **similar** bikes, but for example with intragrated derailleur in the hub, or without disc brakes. I checked all found recommendations, and as the result "a lot" narrowed to just this Trek.

Comment: When I say plenty I mean that a lot of the manufacturers do them, but each manufacturer has probably 1 or 2 bikes in their range that match your precise specifications.  Take this one from a quick search on halfords website, http://www.halfords.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/product_storeId_10001_catalogId_10151_productId_810603_langId_-1_categoryId_165534.  It also has 26" wheels  You just need to know what terminology to look for.  Here's one from Giant with large wheels, http://www.wiggle.co.uk/giant-seek-1-2011/

Comment: Indeed, thank you -- I see it will be hard to find them, because for example Seek 1 is in category "Adventure". I will keep this post open for a while, maybe somebody else add few hints more.

Comment: @macias actually the post could/should be open forever, so that more answers can keep coming.

Comment: Sure, it is still opened, I just marked as solved. So anyone can add more types.

Comment: I like to differentiate between "hybrid" and "commuter". To me the Kona Dew series is more commuter than hybrid. I take hybrid to mean something more upright, potentially with a front suspension/seat suspension and generally a bike less performance oriented and more comfort oriented.

Answer (score 1):

I have two: a "Kona Dr Dew", and a "Giant Seek 1".

They both have the larger-sized wheels.

I found it difficult to find the same, except with with the smaller wheels and lighter: [Light-weight ladies bike](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/6379/1097)

When I went around bike shops in the city, I found each specialized in a different range of bikes: e.g., neighbourhood bikes under $500; racers over $2000; etc. The shop I bought these from seems to stock several in the maybe $500 to $2000 range.